# Android Wear: API to fetch medical parameters from app?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, medical

I was wondering if there is a way in an Android app to download medical parameters from an Android Wear device capable of measuring such. To be specific, I would be particularly interested in fetching the heart rate, blood oxygen saturation & body temperature.

The only thing I have found in the internet was [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/HealthFields), although I could not find *any* implementations using this class, so I have doubts if this is still functional. The reason why I am asking is that there is no specific information available in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch those parameters directly, you have to use the Google Fit API to get these details. There are some code samples available [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/samples).